# Слайдер для сайта

Tags: jquery

Собственно нужно поставить такой слайдер: [ссылка](http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/39139.html).

Построил для начала такую же html форму, подключил jquery c гугла и использующиеся скрпиты: jquery.min.js, jquery.easing.1.3.js, tms-0.3.js, tms_presets.js
Добавил код вызова:

```
<script>
jQuery(window).load(function () {
    jQuery('.slider')._TMS({
        duration: 600,
        easing: 'easeOutQuad',
        preset: 'simpleFade',
        nextBu: '.slider-next',
        prevBu: '.slider-prev',
        slideshow: 9000,
        banners: 'fromLeft',
        waitBannerAnimation: false,
        pauseOnHover: true
    });
});
</script>
```

Собственно переход картинок работает, а вот переход текстов нет. Конкретно контейнеры с классом "banner".

Который час сижу и не могу понять, что пропустил. Подскажите, пожалуйста. Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Ну вы скиньте сюда полный код, станет понятнее. А вы в консоль заглядывали на наличие ошибок?

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас стоит какой-нибудь `adblock`, то проблема может быть и в нём.

Comment: Не, на странице шаблона у меня все нормально показывает, а у меня нет. У контейнеров с классом banner должнен меняться стиль поочередно, а этого не происходит.

Comment: а можно ссылочку на то, что у вас получилось?